# using for loop for number of similar methods

Tags: javascript, for-loop, methods

I have the following code and i want to use these methods inside for loop. Is it possible? if yes, then how?

```
        tree(student0,0);
        tree(student1,1); 
        tree(student2,2);
```

Comment: Put your students in an array instead of using 3 variables. Then you can use a loop easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a FOR EACH loop instead if you have a collection of students. Please specify the language you are using. This could look something like this in javascript :

```
int i = 0;
for(s in studentList){
    tree(s, i);
    i++;
}
```

Where "studentList" is a list (or any other collection) containing studend0, student1, student3, etc.

Comment: can you specify what is studentList here?

Comment: Edited the post for you, could you be more specific on how you get student0 student1 and student3 variables from?

Comment: @Yann, your code has some errors, within the for loop, who is the `s` variable? with javascript, in a loop, you need to use `studentList[vars]`

Comment: Yes sorry, I miss-typed it. Corrected now. Where do you get stuent1 2 and 3 from please? I can't help you without this information.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that in some place in your code you have

```
var student0 = someFuntionGetStuden(0);
var student1 = someFuntionGetStuden(1);
var student2 = someFuntionGetStuden(2);
```

instead you can do like this

```
var students = [];
students.push(someFuntionGetStuden(0));
students.push(someFuntionGetStuden(1));
students.push(someFuntionGetStuden(2));

cont=0;
for(i in students){
  tree(students[i],cont++);
}
```

Comment: no, we don't, read this [The For/In Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) is the last section in the page.